# Detect when clicking on another input after a focusout with Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

Consider that I have a page with multiple lines of text.

When then user clicks on it, it turns into multiple text inputs so he can modify it.
When he clicks outside the text input, its is saved and the input is replaced by the text.
But if he clicks on another text input, I don't want to save it for now, so he doesn't have to click multiple times on a line to modify it.

I was able to that using the `'focusout'` event. I detect that the user clicks ont another input using jQuery's `e.relatedTarget`.

It works great with Chrome but Firefox doesn't support well focusout. `e.relatedTarget`is always `null`

How can I achieve something similar with firefox ?

```js
$('input').on('focusout', function(e) {
  if (e.relatedTarget != null) {
    $('#display').html("don't save for now")
  } else {
    $('#display').html("save the inputs");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that *relatedTarget* is not very useful in Firefox.

The workaround is to explicitly check what element recieves the focus. This is not available during the *focusout* event (as the new element has not received focus yet), *but it will be directly thereafter*. Using a timeout of 0 to move the request to the end of the current execution queue will reliable allow you to get the newly focused element, and check if it is one of the inputs or not.

```js
$('input').on('focusout', function(e) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if ($(document.activeElement).is('input')) {
      $('#display').html("don't save for now")
    } else {
      $('#display').html("save the inputs");
    } 
  }, 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
<div id="display"></div>
```